# iOS GUI for program that uses command line API?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a GUI frontend in iOS for a chess-like game engine where the API via std input/output. The API it adopts is called the [Universal Shogi Interface](http://hgm.nubati.net/usi.html). It allows decoupling of the GUI and engine so that one can swap out either component without much trouble.

This works fine when building and running via Terminal of course. I also know that I can create a macOS GUI for it by using `NSTask` but how would I incorporate such a program into an iOS app where `NSTask` isn't available?

Is there a way to spawn a subprocess in iOS which I can then connect UI buttons to send text commands to the subprocess? (and likewise, labels to read stdout from the program)

Or is would I have to go into the source code of the engine and connect call the functions themselves? That seems like it would defeat the purpose of having a GUI protocol in the first place. Or would I have to port the entire engine into Swift myself?

Comment: Would you consider `openpty(3)` to create a pseudotreminal and `dup2(2)`ing it to stdin/stdout/stderr and then launch the c++ code? It should get around that you cannot use `NSTask`, but it takes a while to read up on it.

Comment: @Mats that's an interesting approach! I'm guessing there would be some sort of Obj-C implementation of those I could use? I might try it out and see if it works. Hopefully, there won't be any performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you mean by "...the engine GUI protocol is to communicate with it via text commands via std input/output." GUI stands for "**Graphical** User Interface". A terminal based text interface is the exact opposite of a graphical user interface. It's a command-line interface. Do you mean that the `API` (not GUI) to the game engine is through a command line?

iOS dos not let apps spawn sub-processes of any kind. You can build third-party frameworks into your app, and those third party frameworks might have an API that takes commands in the form of text input.

It might also be possible to have a 3rd party app running at the same time and taking commands via a custom URL scheme, but iOS doesn't really support the kind of multiprocessing where this makes sense, unless maybe you're using the split-screen interface on iPads in iOS 10 & 11, and I'm not sure if/how well that would work.

Comment: I meant that I wanted to create a GUI on top of a program that uses a command line interface. So yeah, the API to the engine is via command line. So when you say framework, does that mean I have to call the program source functions that would normally parse the standard input?

Comment: It sounds like it, yes. You haven't provided enough information about your "C++ game engine" to be able to tell conclusively. What is it, and how is it provided? Is it a code library? What API does it provide?

Comment: And can you go back and edit your question to clarify? The first sentence as written doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's a shogi engine which is basically japanese chess. Shogi engines use a very similar API that most modern chess engines use called [Universal Shogi Interface](http://hgm.nubati.net/usi.html) that specifies how the engine to GUI connection should work. The purpose is to allow separate development of GUIs and engines i.e. allow engine or GUI interchangeability via decoupling. I've updated my question to be more clear

Comment: Do you think maybe I could include the C++ code with the bridging header and then use some sort of [unix socket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) to send text commands to the engine which would be running in a loop in the background? I think it would be a separate thread and not a sub process but I'm not entirely sure how that works on iOS.